# How does bcma relate to brcmsmac?

Tags: wifi, drivers, kernel-modules, broadcom

I am trying to solve some issues with my wireless connection and trying to learn something on the way. From [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333424/how-can-i-check-the-information-of-currently-installed-wifi-drivers) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) I got to know two different ways to know my wireless driver. Thing is, I get two different results:

The first method, `sudo lshw -C network` gives me the follwing:

```
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac
```

While the second, `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` gives me this:

```
Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

From my list of drivers I can find both `brcmsmac` and `bcma`:

```
> lsmod | grep brcmsmac
brcmsmac              563061  0 
cordic                 12574  1 brcmsmac
brcmutil               15579  1 brcmsmac
mac80211              652777  1 brcmsmac
cfg80211              498458  2 brcmsmac,mac80211
bcma                   52320  2 brcmsmac
```

So, what are exactly these two doing?

Answer (score 3):

Broadcom's hardware design includes a standard PCI/PCIe interface module, which is identical in many of their products. Then there is Broadcom's own proprietary interface bus that can have one or more product-specific modules attached to it.

The `bcma` module is just the driver for the PCI/PCIe interface module, which will act as a "bridge" between the PCI/PCIe bus and Broadcom's proprietary bus. Once loaded, it will identify the other modules on the Broadcom bus and auto-load drivers for them if possible.

The `brcmsmac` is the driver for the actual WiFi hardware module. Since that hardware module is not actually present on the PCI(e) bus, `lspci` can only show the driver for the part that is actually connected to the PCI(e) bus.

You would have to have a new command like `lsbcma` to tell you more details about the contents of the Broadcom bus... as far as I know, such a command does not actually exist, but I think the diagnostic information that the `bcma` module outputs to `dmesg` when loaded can be used for the same purpose, as the Broadcom bus is usually pretty simple.

The `brcmutil` kernel module contains some code that can be shared between the different Broadcom WiFi modules (`brcmsmac` and `brcmhmac`).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same questions as you. In my case, the wireless controler is a Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 and the manufacturer and model numbers are 14e4 and 4727 :

`$ lspci -nn -s 03:00 |grep -i net
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)`

1 - The module alias of the controler is bcma :

`$ cat /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.alias | grep -i 14e4 |grep -i 4727
alias pci:v000014E4d00004727sv*sd*bc*sc*i* bcma`

bcma is loaded first and is in charge of the controler interface

2 - brmsmac depends on bcma

`# modinfo brcmsmac |grep depends
depends:        bcma,mac80211,brcmutil,cfg80211,cordic`

it is loaded after bcma and is in charge of the wireless protocol

3 - bcma-pci-bridge is not recognized as a driver :

`# modinfo bcma-pci-bridge
modinfo: ERROR: Module bcma-pci-bridge not found.`

so my guess is that bcma-pci-bridge is probably a "free name" used to remember that the controler needs 2 drivers ....

I am not an expert, it is just my guess

Comment: You can also use `udevadm` to see the complete device/driver stack; maybe that'll help.